# AttributeError: 'Alien' object has no attribute 'rect'

Tags: python

```
def _create_fleet(self):
    """Create the fleet of aliens."""
    # Create an alien and find the number of aliens in a row.
    # Spacing between each alien is equal to one alien width.
    alien = Alien(self)
    alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
    available_space_x = self.settings.screen_width - (2 * alien_width)
    number_aliens_x = available_space_x // (2 * alien_width)
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly, and also if you could describe the problem you are having that would be helpful

Comment: Your example doesn't show how the Alien class is defined. Please edit your question to include that information. The error you're getting is very straightforward: The alien instance does not have a rect attribute. This can be because 1) You forgot to set the rect attribute, 2) You only set the rect attribute in certain scenarios and this isn't one of them, 3) you deleted the rect attribute after it was set, or 4) you have more than one Alien class and accidentally used the wrong one. There may be other scenarios that I'm not thinking of at the moment.